# UIPanGestureRecognizer to implement scale and rotate an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uipangesturerecognizer

There is a UIView A. I put a icon on view A and try to use pan gesture to scale and rotate this view A. The scale function works fine but I can't make rotation work. The code is as following. Any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
- (void)scaleAndRotateWatermark:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
        || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
    {

        UIView *child = gesture.view;
        UIView *view = child.superview;

        CGPoint translatedPoint = [gesture translationInView:view];

    CGPoint originCenter = child.center;
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(child.centerX+translatedPoint.x, child.centerY+translatedPoint.y);

    float origX = originCenter.x;
    float origY = originCenter.y;
    float newX = newCenter.x;
    float newY = newCenter.y;

    float originDis = (origX*origX) + (origY*origY);
    float newDis = (newX*newX) + (newY*newY);

    float scale = newDis/originDis;

    view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, scale, scale);
    // rotation calulate here 

    // need your help

    // end of rotation

    [guesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:_videoPreviewLayer];
    }
}
```